# Java Run Time Error Path and Classpath

Tags: java

I'm  new to Java. I have written a hello world program, but when I try to compile it, it says

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

I have tried many ways by searching the same on google. I have set the path and class path too in environment variables. But it doesn't work.

ClassPath:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;.
```

path:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin
```

I know that this is not a question to ask in this site. But I hope that someone helps me.

Comment: What command are you executing?

Comment: Did you `javac` the file before attempting to run it?

Comment: Yeah first **javac hello.java** then it creates a hello.class. then **java hello.class**

Comment: Its not working even if i use **java hello** instead of **java hello.class**